# How to set a default action in WinForms(c#) for dragdrop?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I currently have a problem relating to the windows forms API in C#. I have an object a set of different objects that can be dragged and dropped on a set of other objects. When I drop an object outside a droppable area I want to be able to handle that with an event in the controller where the drag started. Is there anyway to do this?

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: You should add listener for drags events.

Comment: No, it is handled by the DragDrop event handler of the control that you dropped on.  The drag source doesn't play any role.  Rather by necessity, the drop target is often located in an entirely different process.  At best you can find out if the drop succeeded, DoDragDrop() has a return value that tells you what happened.

Comment: Okay what I need is to know if the drop was cancelled. A cancelled drop in my definition is the user dropping on a non droppable surface. How would I do this?